# i want to display special characters from mysql to jtextfield using jbutton.my code is working only numbers

Tags: java, mysql, swing

```
private void jbutton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    try
    {
        MainClass mc=new MainClass();

        Connection connection;          
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection(mc.StrUrl,mc.StrUid,mc.StrPwd);
        ResultSet rs;

        String StrQr="";
        if (prid.getText().trim().length()>0 )
        {
            StrQr=StrQr + " and pid = " + prid.getText().trim() + " ";
        }

        if (StrQr.length()==0)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter search critaria.");
            return;
        }


        PreparedStatement st=connection.prepareStatement("select pid, pname,pslno,pcategory,pqty,ppurcst,plpurcst,psalprc,pcmprc from addproducts where 1=1 " + StrQr + " order by pid");
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"connected");

        while (rs.next()) {  
           purcst.setText(rs.getString("ppurcst"));
           salprc.setText(rs.getString("psalprc"));
           prid.setText(rs.getString("Pid"));
           prname.setText(rs.getString("Pname"));
           category.setText(rs.getString("Pcategory"));
           cprc.setText(rs.getString("Pcmprc"));
           qnty.setText(rs.getString("Pqty"));
           slno.setText(rs.getString("Pslno"));
           lpurcst.setText(rs.getString("plpurcst"));
        }
     rs.close();
    }
            catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
        //System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

code display only pid = 104 like numbers .
it cant display special charectors( _,- )pid= A_1103like anybody can help me.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'A' in 'where clause'

i declare pid as varchar in mysql

Answer (score 1):

`A_1103` needs to be quoted, otherwise MySQL will try and resolve it to a column value.

```
... pid = 'A_1103' ...
```

In fact, you should be relying on `PreparedStatement` in order to prevent possible SQL injection problems.

See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

For example...

```
Connection connection;          
connection=DriverManager.getConnection(mc.StrUrl,mc.StrUid,mc.StrPwd);
ResultSet rs;

// I'm assuming there are other elements to this query that
// may be included, otherwise this is a lot of overhead
// for little benifi...
List values = new ArrayList(5);
String StrQr="";
if (prid.getText().trim().length()>0 )
{
    StrQr += " and pid = ? ";
    values.add(prid.getText().trim());
}

if (StrQr.length()==0)
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter search critaria.");
    return;
}


PreparedStatement st=connection.prepareStatement("select pid, pname,pslno,pcategory,pqty,ppurcst,plpurcst,psalprc,pcmprc from addproducts where 1=1 " + StrQr + " order by pid");
// Bind the values to the parameters
for (int index = 0; index < values.size(); index++) {
    st.setObject(index + 1, values.get(index));
}
rs = st.executeQuery();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"connected");
```

Answer (score 1):

In prepared statement you have to set a `?` or any parameter and bind the value.

```
 String StrQr="";
        if (prid.getText().trim().length()>0 )
        {
            StrQr=StrQr + " and pid = ? ";
        }
...
PreparedStatement st=connection.prepareStatement("select pid, pname,pslno,pcategory,pqty,ppurcst,plpurcst,psalprc,pcmprc from addproducts where 1=1 " + StrQr + " order by pid");
        if (prid.getText().trim().length()>0 )
            st.bind(1prid.getText().trim() )
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"connected");
```